# "welche" translated as "some"?

Tags: word-usage, german-to-english

> Wenn die mit Abschüssen ist kein Problem "aber" es gibt **welche** mit Kanonen und dann hast du ein Problem.

Can "welche" here be translated as "some"?

Also, is "aber" used correctly? In case my sentence is grammatical, will it have the same meaning if I don't add "aber" at all? For example:

> Wenn die mit Abschüssen ist kein Problem es gibt **welche** mit Kanonen und dann hast du ein Problem.

Comment: Die Sätze sind kein gültiges Deutsch. Das in Anführungsstriche gesetzte *aber* ist vollkommen crazy. "Wenn die mit Abschüssen kein Problem ist (sind?), aber es gibt welche mit Kanonen und dann hast Du ein Problem."

Comment: Could you please explain what the sentence is intended to be about? I think it is impossible to help you out with correcting the sentence without that information.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your examples. The most important: nouns are always capitalized in German. Also, there is a main clause missing in the first part of the first snippet, and a comma or full stop in front of the second main clause lead by *aber* is missing. Same for the third main clause lead by *und*.

> Wenn **es** die mit **A**bschüssen **sind,** ist **es** kein **P**roblem‍**,** aber es gibt welche mit <s>kannonen</s> **K**anonen‍**,** und dann hast du ein **P**roblem.

The phrase *es gibt welche* means *there are those*.

You may skip the *aber* but not the comma leading the second main clause. It's an interjection meaning *but*.

Also, I doubt *Abschüsse* is the correct word in this context. It means *launches* or *kills*.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess the translation would be this : If they are shooting, it is not a problem, but there are some with cannons and then you have a problem.

Comment: Don't translate the continous aspect into a noun. Simply skip it. It's not important to German ears. *Es ist kein Problem, wenn sie (einfach nur) schießen, aber es gibt welche mit Kanonen, und dann hast du ein Problem.*

Comment: Ich vermute gemeint ist: "Wenn die mit Abschüssen kein Problem ist, aber es gibt welche mit Kanonen und dann hast du ein Problem.", nur das statt "Abschüssen" eine leichtere Waffengattung als Kanonen gemeint ist, etwa "Wenn die (Galeeren?) mit Gewehren kein Problem sind, aber es gibt welche mit Kanonen ...".  Das ominöse Etwas mit Abschüssen könnte auch im Singular stehen - die Queen Victoria. Ohne Kontext aber nicht zu beantworten. Offene Fragen sollte man aber immer erst in Kommentaren klären und Fehler, die orthogonal zur Frage sind, korrigieren.